# LinqToSQL and the exception " ExecuteReader requires an open and available Connection."

Tags: linq-to-sql, exception, executereader

I have a collection called dbUsers of type IQueryable

These are pulled from a linqtosql database context i.e.

```
IQueryable<Data.LinqToSQL.User> dbUsers = DBContext.Users
```

Calling ToList on this object:

```
IList<Data.LinqToSQL.User> users = dbUsers.ToList();
```

Results in an exception:

ExecuteReader requires an open and available Connection. The connection's current state is connecting.

What am I doing wrong here?

Cheers

Comment: Are you creating an object of the DbContext class ??

Comment: Yes. The error doesnt seem to always occur. I do have other other code talking to DBContext.Users which may be contributing to the problem

Answer (score 2):

see if this works for you:

```
IList<Data.LinqToSQL.User> users = (from u in DBContext.Users select u).ToList();
```

if not you might need to do something like:

```
DBContext context = new DBContext();
IList<Data.LinqToSQL.User> users = (from u in context.Users select u).ToList();
```

Comment: Whats the difference between these two examples? Is this causing the DB connection to be closed differently?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a threading problem with the DataContext. I am getting similar problems. Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/650059/strange-behaviour-with-structuremap-asp-mvc-visual-studio-linqtosql#651424) for more details.

Additionally [read this](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/246222.aspx) and [this](http://www.tigraine.at/2009/04/22/locking-with-linq-to-sqls-deferred-execution-in-an-iqueryablet-szenario/).