# Should i use structuremap to handle lifecycle of my linq datacontext?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, structuremap

Is it ok to use SM to handle my linq datacontext lifetime or just create datacontext instance inside repository constructor? I heard from you will have memory leak problem in SM if you let it handle the datacontext. As commented by Rob Connery in this thread. See the comment below. [Strange behaviour with StructureMap / ASP.MVC / Visual Studio / LinqToSql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/650059/strange-behaviour-with-structuremap-asp-mvc-visual-studio-linqtosql)

I'm using SM and asp.net mvc . It seems that im getting my memory increased eventually even context is disposed.

Comment: How are you handling the context? StructureMap will not automatically dispose of your context, unless you use a nested container for it. If not using nested container you need to dispose the context from the client using it. Typically you create a context at the beginning of a request and dispose of it at the end of the request.

Answer (score 0):

I let Unity handle the lifetime of my LinqToSql context on and MVC app and have never had any problems.

In general, I don't see why an IoC container would have problems managing the lifetime of its objects. If StructureMap does (as mentioned in the thread you reference), you probably shouldn't do it then. :)

I guess your options are to either use a different framework, or let the Repository instantiate its context.

Comment: Hi Esteban, Is unity any good? does it have a rich documentation? i'm beginning to feel awkward towards SM as it lacks full documentation and complete examples :-)

Comment: @Petrick Lim: The latest version on Unity is great; I realize that all the cool kids use SM, but Unity does what we need very well. I like it because it's small (just one small DLL), and there's tons of documentation and MSDN.