# Scoped DataContext intermittently raises ExecuteReader error

Tags: c#, multithreading, linq-to-sql, datacontext

Our application follows the approach of maintaining a DataContext per Thread/HttpContext, using the DataContextFactory class outlined by Rick Strahl on his [blog](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/246222.aspx), including the amendment to the Key mentioned by Richard (use of type.AssemblyQualifiedName).

The solution appeared sound (although in most cases a different approach may be better), however while using this I have seen intermittent errors appearing in the application:

> ExecuteReader requires an open and
>   available Connection. The connection's
>   current state is closed.

I access the datacontext throughout the code using the below property, that is part of my DataContext's class:

```
/// <summary>
/// Returns the current datacontext for the thread or HttpContext, creating one if it does not exist.
/// </summary>
public static SharedDataContext Current
{
    get
    {
        return DataContextFactory.GetScopedDataContext<SharedDataContext>();
    }
}
```

Being intermittment I'm having a hard time pinning this down. Does anyone know what I might doing wrong, or have a good idea how I might be able to debug this problem?

---

Note this could possibly be a duplicate of the *unanswered* question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/441293/linqtosql-and-the-exception-executereader-requires-an-open-and-available-connec)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We now use a custom DataContextFactory that maintains datacontexts per-transaction. The only other main change was use of [ThreadStatic] for the properties, rather than manually accessing via Thread.Get/SetData

Since this change the problem no longer seems to appear, and as no other answers have been put forward, I'm suggesting [ThreadStatic] as the solution